# Mapping to insert comment at the end of a line

Tags: vimscript, comments

I'm currently writing a plugin to quickly appends commented `TODO:` codetags to the end of a line in any file type.

How can I make vim make use of it's `commenstring` feature to append a comment that corresponds to the filetype?

I am currently entering those manually but I feel like there may be a more platform agnostic way to do this...

Here is what some of my maps look like right now:

```
" Markdown todo's
autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <buffer> td o<Esc>o<Esc>O[comment]:<Space>#<Space>TODO:<Space>
autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <buffer> TD 0/TODO:<Enter>kd2j
" Vim todo's
autocmd FileType vim nnoremap <buffer> td A<Space><Space>"TODO:<Space>
autocmd FileType vim nnoremap <buffer> TD 0/"TODO:<Enter>d$
" PHP todo's
autocmd FileType php nnoremap <buffer> td A<Space><Space>//TODO:<Space>
autocmd FileType php nnoremap <buffer> TD j0?//TODO:<Enter>d$
" Javascript todo's
autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap <buffer> td A<Space><Space>//TODO:<Space>
autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap <buffer> TD j0?//TODO:<Enter>d$
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of `:execute` and `substitute`. The idea would be to use `substitute` to replace the `%s`  in the `commentstring`  by your `TODO` and then use `execute` to forge the content of the mapping.

Your js mapping could be something like this:

```
nnoremap td :execute "norm! A  " . substitute(&commentstring, '%s', 'TODO ', '')<CR>A
```

Where

- `execute` lets you execute a command forged from a concatenation of strings.
- The concatenated strings are

  - `norm! A` to execute  `A` as in normal mode (The `!` is important if your users remaps `A`)
  - `substitute(&commentstring, '%s', 'TODO ', '')` is the `commentstring` with `%s`  replaced by `TODO`
- `<CR>` validates the `execute` command
- The final `A` allows the user continue to type their comment.

Relevant help topics:

- [`:h 'commentstring'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27commentstring%27)
- [`:h :execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3aexecute)
- [`:h substitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29)

You could also have a look at the source code of [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) to see how they use `'commentstring'`.

Comment: That's awesome! [This reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32190021/2325057) suggests that markdown comments should have their own line. Do you know how I could make Comment start a new line for .md file? I tried adding `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.md set filetype=markdown | let Comment="foo" | let EndComment="bar"` to my vimscript plugin but it isn't detected... So I can't even try to add a new line using `\n [comment]: `.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `let Comment="foo"` actually. Maybe your solution could be to setup up `'commentstring`  by yourself for markdown files with something like `setlocal commentstring="\n[comment]: # %s"`? (I haven't tested that I'm not sure it works)